# Is Lightdm-webkit-greeter necessary to run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter, webkit

I want to get rid of lightdm-webkit-greeter due to the errors when I boot into Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Is it possible to run Ubuntu without lightdm? I don't want to mess up my system by removing it. I have everything set perfect. Keep in mind that I am using Noobslab's MacBuntu environment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [noobslab manual](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/mbuntu-y-macbuntu-transformation-pack.html) installing their lightdm-webkit-greeter theme may lead to errors. You can remove their theme, reboot and see if it helped.

```
sudo apt-get remove mbuntu-y-lightdm-v5
```

lightdm-webkit-greeter itself shouldn't be removed since it's the app that does the log in and desktop environment start.

Comment: ok it says "E: Unable to locate package mbuntu-y-lightdm-v5"

Comment: I restarted my system multiple times and it seems a bit off and on with the boot errors. I tried to remove the crash reports and it does help for the next start up.

Comment: What are the boot errors that you get?

Comment: apport gtk-root